# Exportar una carpeta hacia otra dentro del mismo directorio luego de importar documentos en bucle foreach

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp

Gusto en saludar, quisiera consultar lo siguiente, tengo un bucle creado para poder importar documentos a una carpeta con un `multiupload`. Ahora necesito poder mover la carpeta creada con todos los documentos luego del bucle creado a una carpeta dentro del mismo directorio.

**Ejemplo:**

Los documentos se exportan a una carpeta con formato `datetime` `20191210111437` al directorio `UploadedFiles` pero quiero mover esa carpeta con todos los documentos a `\UploadedFiles\01_import` luego de terminar el bucle `FOREACH` y que todos los documentos hayan llegado a la carpeta correspondiente.

Adjunto codigo del bucle que crea documentos y la carpeta para ver en que me pueden ayudar, se que hay un `directory.move` pero me tira **error** y no se como corregirlo o como se debe hacer.

Saludos y adjunto codigo:

```
public ActionResult UploadFiles(HttpPostedFileBase[] files)
{
  //Ensure model state is valid
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {   //iterating through multiple file collection 
            foreach (HttpPostedFileBase file in files)
            {
                //Checking file is available to save.
                if (file != null)
                {
                    var InputFileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                    var ServerSavePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/UploadedFiles/"+"/"+DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") +"/"));
                    if (!Directory.Exists(ServerSavePath))
                    {
                        //If Directory (Folder) does not exists. Create it.
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(ServerSavePath);
                    }
                    //Save file to server folder
                    file.SaveAs(ServerSavePath + Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));
                    //assigning file uploaded status to ViewBag for showing message to user.
                    ViewBag.UploadStatus = files.Count().ToString() + " Archivos subidos correctamente.";
                }
if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(ServerSavePath))
{
 System.IO.Directory.Move(ServerSavePath, "~/UploadedFiles/01_import");
}
            }
        }
```

Comment: Efectivamente, tu método es `directory.move`. Dinos el error que te da, será más fácil ayudarte. Tambien puedes ver los posible errores en la [documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.move?view=netframework-4.8) para intentar subsanar el problema.

Comment: Es que nunca he utilizado directory move No se puede encontrar una parte de la ruta de acceso.
Detalles de la excepción: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: No se puede encontrar una parte de la ruta de acceso.

Adjunto codigo que me faltó
if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(ServerSavePath))
                        {
                            System.IO.Directory.Move(ServerSavePath, "~/UploadedFiles/01_import");
                        }

Comment: @RogerTorné ahi edite el codigo en la pregunta, eso si aclaro que nunca he usado el movedirectory y quiero mover el resultado del bucle final a "~/UploadedFiles/01_import" que es lo que no se como hacer y me tira el error que no se encuentra una parte de la ruta de acceso, muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando utilizas `directory.move` tienes que indicarle el origen y destino con un path que se corresponda con el del sistema operativo, no del servidor web. Lo haces bien en la carpeta de origen, pero no en la de destino.

Debes cambiar la siguiente línea

```
System.IO.Directory.Move(ServerSavePath, "~/UploadedFiles/01_import");
```

Por esta

```
System.IO.Directory.Move(ServerSavePath, Server.MapPath("~/UploadedFiles/01_import"));
```

Comment: Me figura el siguiente error
No se puede crear un archivo que ya existe.

[IOException: No se puede crear un archivo que ya existe.


                    var ServerSavePath1 = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/UploadedFiles/" + "/" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + "/"));

                    if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(ServerSavePath1))
                    {
                        System.IO.Directory.Move(ServerSavePath1, Server.MapPath("~/UploadedFiles/01_import"));
                    }

Comment: La documentación dice: Si intenta trasladar un directorio a un directorio que ya existe, se producirá una IOException. Por ejemplo, se producirá una excepción si intenta pasar c:\MiDir a c:\Public y c:\Public ya existe.

Comment: Muchas gracias consulta, se refiere a que debo dejar el directorio en blanco y que lo cree automaticamente??, que me entra la duda en ese punto porque tengo la carpeta /UploadedFiles/01_import creada, estaba leyendo pero es un poco complejo esta parte de mover directorios, muchas gracias por sus respuestas.